# InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element - SingleOrDefault()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, invalidoperationexception

```
using (var db = new ABC())
{

for (int column = rangeClass2.Start.Column; column <= rangeClass2.End.Column; column++)
{
   var classValue = censusSheet.Cells[row, column].Value;
   var description = censusSheet.Cells[3, 27].Value;
 lifeReductionByData.Add(classASheet.getClassFromExcelPivotedValuedreductionBy<tbl_Life_Reduction_By>(25, 1, 33, 4, lifeReductionByClassMapper).FirstOrDefault());
 for (int i = 0; i < lifeReductionByData.Count; i++)
 {
     lifeReductionByData[i].Class = classesValue[x];
     lifeReductionByData[i].UUID = censusSheet.GetValue(25, 27).ToString();
 }
}
var entry = new tbl_Life_Master() { UUID = uuidVar };
entry.tbl_Life_Reduction_By = lifeReductionByData;
context.tbl_Life_Master.Add(entry);
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

By searching on Stack Overflow, it is clear to me that `FirstOrDefault()` is the best approach to avoid this execption. But if I want to add multiple records in my list once then what is the solution? As '**getClassFromExcelPivotedValuedreductionBy**' here is returning 3 records. Please help me out in this.

Comment: What do you want to happen in case there are multiple values?

Comment: @usr I want to add it in 'lifeReductionByData' which is a list of database table declared as 'List<tbl_Life_Reduction_By> lifeReductionByData = new List<tbl_Life_Reduction_By>();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I want to add multiple records in my list once then what is the solution?

You mean you want to add *all* the results? Assuming that `lifeReductionByData` is a `List<T>` for the appropriate type, you can just use [`List<T>.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc):

```
var query = classASheet.getClassFromExcelPivotedValuedreductionBy<tbl_Life_Reduction_By>(25, 1, 33, 4, lifeReductionByClassMapper);
lifeReductionByData.AddRange(query);
foreach (var item in lifeReductionByData)
{
    item.Class = classesValue[x];
    item.UUID = censusSheet.GetValue(25, 27).ToString();
}
```

Note the use of `foreach` here instead of the index. Now, if `lifeReductionByData` was actually empty before this piece of code, and you don't need it afterwards, you can just iterate over the query itself:

```
var query = classASheet.getClassFromExcelPivotedValuedreductionBy<tbl_Life_Reduction_By>(25, 1, 33, 4, lifeReductionByClassMapper);
foreach (var item in query)
{
    item.Class = classesValue[x];
    item.UUID = censusSheet.GetValue(25, 27).ToString();
}
```

If you *do* need the list afterwards, but it was empty beforehand, then I'd use:

```
var query = classASheet.getClassFromExcelPivotedValuedreductionBy<tbl_Life_Reduction_By>(25, 1, 33, 4, lifeReductionByClassMapper);
var list = query.ToList();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.Class = classesValue[x];
    item.UUID = censusSheet.GetValue(25, 27).ToString();
}
```

Next up, I'd rename `getClassFromExcelPivotedValuedreductionBy` to a) be briefer; b) follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Actually this piece of code is already in a loop. Its adding 3 results each time when the loop runs. WIll that affect anything?

Comment: @JasneetSingh: Well it's hard to tell from just the description. This is what happens when you only give us part of the context, I'm afraid... but if you take the time to work through the answer (e.g. reading the linked documentation) to understand what's going on, you should be able to work out how to apply it to your situation.

Comment: @JasneetSingh: Well why are you overwriting the `Class` and `UUID` of *all* the entries in the list, including the ones you'd already written in previous iterations? That doesn't sound like a good plan. In the end, we're really having to make wild guesses about what you can achieve - and very little of it seems to have anything to do with the exception you've specified in the question.